# Javascript - Display array in Frontend line by line

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let data=["First", "Second"]
```

I'm trying to display it line by line (without comma) like so:

First

Second

I tried using split

```
let data.split("\n")
```

but this will return

```
["First,Second"]
```

How can I take this data and display it line by line inside without the comma?

Comment: Use `data.join('\n')`

Comment: `split` takes a string and split it to an array, while `join` will take an array and combine it to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to split the data as it's already separated, what you have to do is join the data using `data.join()`.

Whatever you pass as a parameter to `data.join()` will be the character placed between your data.

So in your case you can either use `data.join(\n)`. (`\n` stands for 'new line')

Or `data.join(<br/>)` if you wish to display your text in plain html. (`<br/>` is a html blank rule tag).